# How to copy a file by URI

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Android 11

Preamble:
I have a deck of cards with URI links to images & video, while this functions on the device that it's created on, it accrued to me that sharing those card decks from one device to another or many will course course quite a problem, as the URIs on the origin device they was created on won't match any other device other than the original.

Problem:
So my concept is; create a temporary directory and copy all the media images & videos the user made, reformat the XML file for the deck to look for the file locally eg. filesDir() and zip up the temporary directory and copy it to downloads so the user can share the zip file to others.

So how do I copy files linked by URI into a directory, so I can zip up and export them?

I've searched, but I can figure out what I should be using.

Comment: You can also zip the files directly from uri i think. Why not?

Comment: And to make a copy of a file of which you have an uri is about the same code as copy from file path. So where would be the problem exactly?

Comment: @blackapps unaware that you can use URIs to add to a zip, however the prerequisite of a zip file is you have a file name an example: content://media/external/images/media/18199 doesn't qualify by itself, you could store 18199 as a file name sure, however I have gone to the trouble of getting the orginal file name from a URI it would be a shame not to use it, I've basically drilled down URI to be akin to Windows Shortcuts on a desktop and not to be trusted.

Comment: `you could store 18199 as a file name sure`That makes no sense. It is not much work to make a function getDisplayName(Uri uri) to give you ... the file name. And as said before: I dont know if one can add files from uries to zip files. Investigate. And otherwise copy. But only copy just before you zip. And delete directly after zipping that file.  It makes no sense to have all those files twice on device.

Comment: found this finally; https://androidfortechs.blogspot.com/2020/12/how-to-convert-uri-to-file-android-10.html - it appears to work, how correct method it might be probably depends on how you look at it.

They wouldn't be twice; lets simplify assuming Deck A.zip holds images and video. A -> given to B a new device as a Zip, B doesn't have A's resources until B imports a Zip when B does so A's resources are extracted and placed in it's on sub folder, the imported Zip can then be discarded.

Comment: Why that link? There is nothing in it that has anything to do with an uri to put in zip files.  It is old stuff. But indeed an answer to the questionj in the subject... And they would be twice on the device if you make a copy. And even three times if you then put the copy in a zip file.

Comment: Why that link? because the code allows/shows me how to copy URIs back to actual files. I can then place them in my cache folder, translate the URIs in "Deck A.xml"  to use paths that relate to the app folder location instead, I can then finally zip the files in the cache folder drop the zip off in /Downloads, clean up the cache folder. The user can then finally copy "DeckA.zip" to a new device, the new device imports "DeckA.zip" extracts it in /files and "Deck A.zip" is discarded, there are no duplicate files for the NEW device, the creator of "*.zip" will do, not my job clean up.

Comment: nb: works in a very similar way WinAMP skins work, which is in part where I got the idea to resolve the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler solution is to create class that will help you identify cards that keeps reference for the URI for local reference. After all you will need is to search deck until you find identifier you passed.
For example

```
data class Card{
   symbol : SomeEnumToRepresentSymbol("S","D","H","C")
   value : int
   identifier get() = this.symbol + this.value
   localUri : URI
}
```

Create **Deck** object to keep your cards and references for uris on each phone independently and you pass identifier from phone to phone

```
val passed : Card
....
deck.find(c->c.identifier == passed.identifier)
```

Comment: Unsure what your trying to do there, I already have a var mydecklist = mutableListOf<Card>() which contains 5 uri variables (sorry if wrong term), thing is while the deck is local to the device the URI's unless the user deletes something should be fine, but if the user wants to share example content://media/external/images/media/18199 won't be the same on another device, my problem is copying the data content://media/external/images/media/18199 references to a temporary directory, then it's just a matter of zipping the content up along with the XML, and drop in downloads folder

Comment: Explain to me a bit more what do you mean by "sharing", is this like playing vs another player so you want to show played card or something like that or other purpose

Comment: okay I'll try, imagine you have 2 players, each round they take turns answering a question and gaining points on choosing the right answer. The cards question could be in any from text, audio, images, video, the text for example could be narrated by an actual human, all of this needs to be stored some place while either being played or created. Shared as in all of that content from a creators [deck of cards] can be copied as a zip to anywhere, then other people also running the my app can import that zip file and play as well, like how WinAmp skins work.

Comment: Okay so if you already have those files locally just remember where the uri is on the phone, and make a key value pair tied to some id. Don't send files every time you will get duplicated files and your app will eat phones storage. Just send id of that card to another phone and take it as a key to get uri stored on that phone